# Python imaging library overlay a bunch of images on another image

Tags: python, windows, algorithm, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a map of gas stations in a video game. I got a piece of code, which defines all those stations. So I made a function in Python.

```
from PIL import Image

output = Image.new("RGBA", (8192, 8192))
a = Image.open("b.png")
def Vector3(xx,yy,zz):
  x = int(xx + 16384)
  z = int(zz + 16384)
  x = x / 4
  z = z / 4

output.paste(a, (int(x - 93), int(z - 297)), a)
Vector3(-7101, 207, -3603)
```

Beacuse the list of stations was just alot of Vector3 commands. Now, my b.png image is a pin (like from a map) acquired [Here](http://www.clker.com/clipart-map-pin-gray.html) and a 8192x8192 map. How to make the pins overlay? So far I have
`ValueError: bad transparency mask`
thrown by my code. Please help.

Comment: Is `b.png` the pin? Does it have a transparent background?

Comment: nevermind. I already found the solution. I gotta add .convert("RGBA") to the b.png which is the pin